# Proving double-angle trig identities

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having some trouble proving trig identities, this time with the double-angle formula. I want to prove that:

$$
\frac{1 + \tan^2 A}{1 - \tan^2 A}=\sec 2A
$$

I know that:

$$
1 - \tan^2 A = \frac{2 \tan A}{\tan 2A}
$$

But I don't know how to get the numerator of the LHS. I also know that:

$$
\sec 2A = \frac{1}{2\sin A \cos A}
$$

But I can't marry them together. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you mean $\dfrac{1+\tan^2 A}{1-\tan^2 A}=\sec 2A$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, $\displaystyle2\sin A\cos A=\sin2A$

If $\displaystyle\sec2A=\frac1{2\sin A\cos A}$

we need $\displaystyle\sec2A=\frac1{\sin2A}\iff1=\frac{\sin2A}{\cos2A}$

$\displaystyle\implies\tan2A=1\iff2A=n\pi+\frac\pi4$ where $n$ is any integer

Now,
$$\frac{1+\tan^2A}{1-\tan^2A}=\frac{1+\dfrac{\sin^2A}{\cos^2A}}{1-\dfrac{\sin^2A}{\cos^2A}}=\frac{\cos^2A+\sin^2A}{\cos^2A-\sin^2A}=\frac1{\cos2A}$$

**Reference** : [Double-Angle Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html)

Comment: I liked the previous formatting of your answer more...if you don't mind

Comment: @Hawk, please find the edited version

Comment: How did you get from $\frac{1+\tan^2A}{1-\tan^2A}$ to $\frac{\cos^2A+\sin^2A}{\cos^2A-\sin^2A}$?

Comment: Yes, this is fine...Your solution is good as always

Comment: @hohner, please find the edited version

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks. One final question: how do you get from $\frac{\cos^2A+\sin^2A}{\cos^2A-\sin^2A}$ to $\frac1{\cos2A}$?

Comment: Wait, I got it. Thanks!